# find and grep: get filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I need to find the reports (.docx files), read them with `docx2txt`, find the second match of "passed" (excluding "not passed") and save these filenames to text file. Here is what I tried:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find . -wholename '*_done/(*Report*.docx' |grep -v appendix)
do
    docx2txt "$f" - | (grep -q -m2 passed || grep -q -v "not passed") || echo $f >> failed
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

But this script gives me an empty file. If I replace `||` to `&&` before `echo`, all filenames are stored into the file. `grep` works fine if it is not in the script, as well as `docx2txt`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [use `while`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @PaulHodges Will the script work correctly in this case, or it's just an advice?

Comment: Just unrelated advice, sorry. It will help simplify stuff though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a lot problems with the grep commands.

`grep -q` *always* exits successfully on the first match.

- With `-q` the `-m2` has no effect. If there is one match `grep` exits successfully. It does not check if there is a second match.
  To check that there are (at least) two matches, count the matches and then use  `test`/`[ ]` to check the number of found matches. If there is at most one `passed` per line, `grep -c` is sufficient. If there can be multiple matches per line, you need `grep -o ... | wc -l`.
- `-q` and `-v` together means: *Is there at least one line that does not contain the pattern?* When `grep` finds such a line it exits successfully. The only way for this command to fail is an input in which every line contains `not passed` (this includes the empty file).
  Matching `passed` but not `not passed` is trickier than one might suspect. If there can be at most one `passed`/`not passed` per line, you can use `grep -v 'not passed' | grep passed`. Otherwise you need a need negative lookbehind, which is only available in perl compatible regular expressions (PCRE).

In addition to that `command | (grep ... || grep ...)` might not do what you expect. `command` produces output only once. After the first `grep` read some of this output, that read part is gone. The second `grep` will then continue reading where the first `grep` stopped.

BTW: `for … in $(find … | grep -v …)` can be turned into a single, safe `find` command using `-not` and `-exec`.

#### Solution

If each line contains at most one `passed`/`not passed`, use

```
find . -wholename '*_done/(*Report*.docx' -not -wholename '*appendix*' \
-exec sh -c '[ $(docx2txt "$0" - | grep -v "not passed" | grep -cm2 passed) = 2 ]' {} \; -print
```

If there can be multiple `passed`/`not passed` per line, you need GNU `grep` or `pcregrep`:

```
find . -wholename '*_done/(*Report*.docx' -not -wholename '*appendix*' \
-exec sh -c '[ $(docx2txt "$0" - | grep -Pom2 "(?<!not )passed" | wc -l) = 2 ]' {} \; -print
```

Comment: `(?<!...)` is a negative look**behind**. To find all `зафиксирован` that are not `зафиксированы` you need a negative look**ahead**: `grep -Pom2 'зафиксирован(?!ы)'`. For more information on lookarounds see [this website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/6770384).

Answer (score 2):

When you run into a problem like this, it's a good idea to remove as much code as possible. If we just take that one line with the multiple `grep` statements, we can first verify that the current expression doesn't work:

```
$ echo passed | ((grep -q -m2 passed || grep -q -v "not passed") || echo failed
$ echo not passed | ((grep -q -m2 passed || grep -q -v "not passed") || echo failed
```

We can see that neither of these commands produces at any output.

Let's think carefully about the logic:

The `||` operator means "if the first command doesn't succeed, run the second command". So in both cases, the first grep succeeds (because both `passed` and `not passed` contain the phrase `passed`). This means the second grep will never run, **and** it means that since the first command was successful, the entire `grep ... || grep ...` command will be successful, and that means the final `echo $f` will never run.

---

I was trying to think of a clever way to solve this, but it seems simplest if we make use of a temporary file:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
tmpfile=$(mktemp docXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" EXIT
for f in $(find . -wholename '*_done/(*Report*.docx' |grep -v appendix)
do
    docx2txt "$f" - | head -2 > $tmpfile
    if grep -q passed $tmpfile && ! grep -q 'not passed' $tmpfile; then
      echo $f >> failed
    fi
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```